# return data inside function from http post

Tags: angularjs

I want to get data pass from a function, the data successfully return inside the success response. However I can't return the data from the function itself.

```
function getStatusPublished(dating, product) 
{
    var datas = "";

    var success = function(response, status, headers, config){
      datas = response;
    }

    var error = function(error, status, headers, config){
      datas = "error";
    }

    var cdnss = "htttp://application_ajax";
    $http.post(cdnss+"&pblishDateVacan="+dating+"&ProjectID="+product)
    .success(success).error(error);

    console.log(datas);
}
```

In the `console.log`, it just said `undefined`.

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: you cannot return the data from the function. An http call is asynchronous and takes time to get data back. A function is synchronous and returns immediately. You probably want to return a promise from your function.

Comment: Can you help me, please, how to do this with promise return?

Comment: Put `console.log(datas);` **INSIDE** the success function

Comment: Alon, I want to return the data from the function itself, not only from the success call.

Comment: There are some good video's on egghead.io for learning how to use promises https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-promises

Comment: So what's @rob wrote is what you need to know about AJAX

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$http.post` method returns a [promise](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#the-promise-api); not data.

To return a promise, simply use a [return statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return).

```
function getStatusPublished(dating, product) {
    var url = "htttp://application_ajax";
    var postData = {};
    var params = {
      pblishDataVacan: dating,
      ProjectId: product
    };
    var config = { params: params };
    var promise = $http.post(url,postData,config);
    //return promise
    return promise;
}
```

To get the data from the promise, use the `.then` method:

```
var promise = getStatusPublished(d, p);

promise.then( function(response) {
    $scope.data = response.data;
    return response.data;
}).catch ( function(response) {
    console.log(response.status);
    throw response;
});
```